# Gradle replacing Maven assembly plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm fairly new to Gradle, and trying to port an existing Maven pom.xml that makes extensive use of maven-assembly-plugin to create various zip files.

In the example below, I'm getting files from various subdirectories (with particular extensions), and then mapping them in a flat structure to a ZIP file.

```
task batchZip(type: Zip) {
  from fileTree('src/main/sas') {
    include('**/*.sas')
    include('**/*.ds')
  }.files
}
```

This puts all the files in the root of the zip.  What I ideally need though, is for the files to live under a particular path in the root of the zip, e.g. /shared/sas.

Is there a way to do this without first copying all the files to a local directory and then zipping that up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task batchZip(type: Zip) {
    into('shared/sas') {
        from { fileTree('src/main/sas').files }
        include('**/*.sas')
        include('**/*.ds')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:into(java.lang.Object)). It seems that if You specify appropriate `into` You'll get the result You're looking for.